# Angular $scope.model wont bind to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
angular.module('demoapp').controller("EventControllerNearPosition", EventControllerNearPosition);
EventControllerNearPosition.$inject = ["$scope", "ApiEventFactory", "ApiPositionFactory", "UserInteractionMessagesFactory", "$location"]

function EventControllerNearPosition($scope, apiEvent, apiPosition, UIMfactory, $location){
UIMfactory.printUserSuccessMessages();
UIMfactory.printUserFailedMessage();

getAllPositions();

function getAllPositions() {
    apiPosition.getAllPositions().then(function(data){
        $scope.positions = data.requested_positions;
    }).error(function(error){
        UIMfactory.addUserFailedMessage("Something went wrong, try again!");
        $location.path("/");
    });
};

$scope.SearchEvent = function(){
    apiEvent.showNearbyEvents($scope.position_id).then(function(nearEvents){
        $scope.events = nearEvents;
    }).error(function(error){
        UIMfactory.addUserFailedMessage("Something went wrong when fetching the events, try again!");
        $location.path("/");
    });
};
};
```

Angular code^

```
<div class="event-container">
<div>
    <h3>Ange position</h3>
    <select id="position" data-ng-model="position_id">
        <option data-ng-repeat="position in positions" value="{{position.id}}">
            {{position.location_name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="SearchEvent()" value="Skicka"/>
</div>
```

The select won't bind the position that i got from i api. I have debugged the application and checked that i get the right values back. I know that similar or "equal" code work in other partial views so i don't understand why it doesn't work here. And also when i press the button for that is going to trigger "SearchEvent" nothing happens in the debugger. Im using firefox if that matters

Thanks for any kind of feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see only one mistake, you should take `data` from response object of `.then` function.

```
function getAllPositions() {
    apiPosition.getAllPositions().then(function(response){
        //change in below line
        $scope.positions = response.data.requested_positions;
    }, function(error){
        UIMfactory.addUserFailedMessage("Something went wrong, try again!");
        $location.path("/");
    });
};
```

Comment: There is no "data" in response. It's sopposed to be response.requested_position. Requested_positions is an array containing the position objects

Answer (score 0):

I could judge well if i could see the data you get in response. But as far as this code snippet is concerned, The `.then()` is not used well. The .then method works as `.then(RESPONSE FUNCTION, ERROR FUNCTION)`
The `.error()` was not necessary to be used.

```
function getAllPositions() {
    apiPosition.getAllPositions().then(function(response){
        $scope.positions = response.data.requested_positions;
    },function(error){
        UIMfactory.addUserFailedMessage("Something went wrong, try again!");
        $location.path("/");
    });
};
```

Comment: The "response" variable i get contains an "requested_position" variable array of objects. It's sopposed to be response.requested_position.

Comment: According to practices, your controller will call a factory method. The factory method will generate the $http request. This would be waiting for response in .then() with $q as promise. if the request gets a response it will do $q.resolve() or else it will do $q.reject. Here if you want to access the data in controller which you received from factory, It will always have a `data` element in which you will find your data you received and the other variables will be holding the information which is not directly related to your output.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. First of all i removed the "s" in response.requested_position(s);

Then i used the answear Pankaj Parkar submited. Except i didn't use the "data" in response.data.requested_positions because i use "$resource" and not "$http" or whatever it is called!

Thanks for all the feedback!!